# docker-compose container isn't hosting files properly when building server first

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webserver

I have to host 2 different web apps from a docker container. My first attempt at this worked, but I didn't like it. I have a lamp-base folder that has the Dockerfile that gets the server working, then a docker-compose.yml file that puts everything together. In my first version for the web apps I did `build: ./lamp-base/` to make them build the web server, but I feel like that's the wrong approach as it leaves me with 3 images (one for each web app and one for the mysql server). I feel like this should be 2 images and 3 containers. 1 image for the mysql container and 1 image for the web server, then the web apps should be able to use the web server. I was able to build it and make it work, kind of.

The problem is, when I go to the URL I defined and added to my local `/etc/hosts` file I get the default welcome to apache page, I don't get my web apps. I honestly can't figure out why it isn't working correctly. The healthchecks pass, so the files are being hosted properly, but I can't access the web pages. This might be a little long, but I'll post up the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml file as well as the default.conf that get's added to the web server. I have asked all the people I know and no one can figure out why I can't reach the webpages, especially since the healthchecks pass. Thank you for bearing with me on this, here are the files...

Dockerfile...

```
FROM centos:7

EXPOSE 80/tcp

RUN yum install epel-release yum-utils -y && yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm -y

RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74 && yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-pdo php-pdo_mysql php-pecl-mcrypt php-sodium php-mbstring php-runtime php-json php-devel php-xml php-soap php-mysqlnd php-intl php-pecl-xlswriter httpd mod_ssl mod_php -y && yum clean all -y && rm /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

ADD httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ADD conf.d/default.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf

CMD /sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

The default.conf file that has the vhosts for the web apps...

```
<VirtualHost my.server1.com:80>
  ServerName my.server1.com
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combinedio
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
  LogLevel notice
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
  RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
  # Set application web root and directory settings
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/server1/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/server1/html">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride none
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/server1/class"
    php_value arg_separator.output ";"
    php_value arg_separator.input ";"
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my.server2.com:80>
  ServerName my.server2.com
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combinedio
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
  LogLevel notice
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
  RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
  # Set application web root and directory settings
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/server2/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/server2/html">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride none
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/server2/class"
    php_value arg_separator.output ";"
    php_value arg_separator.input ";"
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I renamed the servers because I don't think I can post the actual server names, sorry.

The docker-compose.yml file...

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
    lamp-net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
services:

    lamp-web:
        build: ./lamp-base/
        image: lamp-web:dev
        networks:
            lamp-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    lamp-mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.4
        container_name: lamp-mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
        volumes:
            - ./sql-files:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            lamp-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        healthcheck:
            test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=password --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
            interval: 3s
            timeout: 2s
            retries: 10
            
    server-one:
        image: lamp-web:dev
        container_name: server-one
        hostname: my.server1.com
        depends_on:
            lamp-mysql:
                condition: service_healthy
        volumes:
            - ./server1:/var/www/server1
            - ./Server1Config.php:/var/www/server1/class/Config.php
        networks:
            lamp-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
        healthcheck:
            test: curl -kf http://server-one/home/landing/ || exit 1
            interval: 3s
            timeout: 2s
            retries: 10
            
    server-two:
        image: lamp-web:dev
        container_name: server-two
        hostname: my.server2.com
        volumes:
            - ./server2:/var/www/server2
            - ./Server2Config.php:/var/www/server2/class/Config.php
        depends_on:
            lamp-mysql:
                condition: service_healthy
            cr-web:
                condition: service_healthy
        networks:
            lamp-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4
        healthcheck:
            test: curl -kf http://server-one/api/mp/inventory || exit 1
            interval: 3s
            timeout: 3s
            retries: 10
```

It all builds correctly, I end up with 2 Images (mysql and server) and 3 containers (mysql, server-one, and server-two) all the healthchecks pass properly, but if I go to `http://my.server1.com` in my browser I only get the default apache welcome page, I don't get my actual server.

I have also tried removing the server from the docker-compose file and just doing `docker build --no-cache . -t lamp-web:dev` in the `/lamp-base` directory, then running the `docker-compose up -d` and again, it all builds properly I get the right containers, the healthchecks pass, but going to the URL in any browser just yields the default welcome to apache page. I can't figure out why the web containers aren't working correctly.

On a side note, if I remove the web server entirely and change the `image: lamp-web:dev` to `build: ./lamp-base/` on both web containers it works correctly, but I end up with a bunch of images. Am I just going about this the wrong way? Should both the web containers have to build their own web server image? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you and sorry for the long post.

Comment: You mention you edited `/etc/hosts`; what have you manually overridden `my.server1.com` to resolve to?

Comment: If you set both of the containers to `build:` the same directory, my expectation is that they would build an identical images, and if you look carefully at the `docker images` output, the two images will have the same image ID.

Comment: A setup I might consider is to set up the two backend services as independent images, that don't do virtual-host routing, but that do `COPY` their specific application code into their image.  Then the "lamp-web" container could be a reverse proxy that doesn't have any code or a PHP interpreter, but instead just forwards requests to one of the backend containers; the virtual-host routing would be here only.  This would have two custom images plus the `mysql` and `httpd` Docker Hub images.